# Is there a way to make GitHub CI build the test merge of a PR, rather than the head of the PR branch?

Tags: git, github, github-actions, github-ci

When I create a PR, GitHub CI (via the `actions/checkout` action) checks out the head of the PR branch. For example, if the head of the PR branch has the SHA `cc87b2733dfbe579a4451b2359191a6c512207c3`, I see this in the GitHub CI log:

```
git checkout --progress --force cc87b2733dfbe579a4451b2359191a6c512207c3
```

Whereas other CI systems check out the *test merge* of the PR. For example, if the PR number is 123, in the Travis CI log I see:

```
git fetch origin +refs/pull/123/merge
git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
```

And in the Appveyor log I see:

```
git fetch -q origin +refs/pull/123/merge
git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
```

Is there a way to make GitHub CI build the test merge of a PR, rather than the head of the PR branch?

Comment: What does the GITHUB_REF environment variable look like? If it's something life `refs/pull/123`, you could try specifying the `ref` input to `checkout` (see https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/master/action.yml for a complete list of inputs) and make it be something like `$(GITHUB_REF)/merge`. Note that that's Bash syntax, not GitHub action YAML syntax; I'm not in the beta so I can't test this idea myself.

Comment: @rmunn thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately `GITHUB_REF` is set to the PR branch name, e.g. `refs/heads/mybranch`. Looking at https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#default-environment-variables it seems like there is currently nothing which can be used to determine the pull request number. BTW - I raised https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/15

Comment: @AdamRalph What event are you using to trigger the workflow? i.e. 
`on:`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*As per https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/15:*

The GitHub docs are misleading:

> If you intend to use the `pull_request` event to trigger CI tests, we recommend that you set up your workflow configuration to listen to the `push` event.

I've discovered that the following works exactly as I want:

```
on:
  push:
  - master
  - release-*
  pull_request:
```

I was concerned that I would get too many builds triggered using the `pull_request` event, since according to the [docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/events-that-trigger-workflows):

> Triggered when a pull request is assigned, unassigned, labeled, unlabeled, opened, edited, closed, reopened, synchronize, ready_for_review, locked, unlocked or when a pull request review is requested or removed.

But it seems that GH actions is clever enough not to trigger a rebuild of a commit that was already built.

Comment: I'm not sure that's always true... I was able get the checks running multiple times off of a PR by pushing, adding a second commit, pushing that, then resetting the branch back to the first commit and force pushing.

Comment: That's not ideal, but I think it's OK. BTW are you sure that the target branch (e.g. master) didn't move on in the meantime? Since that would mean the test merge would necessarily be different. But I guess this is happening regardless of that, since the force push means a new merge commit is created, and that commit would never have been built yet.